# Is the sequence of return times a Markov Chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, stopping-times

> Let $\{X_n\} $ be an irreducible Markov chain on a finite state space $S$. Take arbitrary subset $A\subset S$, $\tau_0=\inf\{n:X_n\in A\}$ and $\tau_{n+1}=\inf \{n>\tau_n: X_n\in A\}$.
>   Is $\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3,...\}$ a Markov chain?

I think that, by letting $Y_n=X_{\tau_n}$, we can use the strong Markov property to show that $\{Y_n\}$ is Markov. So I am wondering if the strong Markov property can also be applied to the sequence of return times as described above. Or maybe that $\{Y_n\}$’s being Markov could imply that return times are Markov as well?

Comment: If $A$ is a singleton then $(\tau_{n+1}-\tau_n)$ is i.i.d. hence $(\tau_n)$ is indeed Markov. As soon as $A$ is larger, simple counterexamples should show that $(\tau_n)$ is not Markov.

Comment: @Did So when $A=S$, I think $\{\tau_n\}$ is Markov as well since $\tau_{n+1}=\tau_n +1$ for all $n$. Am I missing something?

Comment: ?? Are you really interested in the case A = S ? Sorry but I fail to see where you are going.

Comment: @Did Okay I misunderstood you. I thought you were saying as $A$ is larger $\{\tau_n\}$ is not Markov

Comment: Yes, when A is larger than a singleton (and of course, smaller than S), the tau process can and often does fail to be Markov.

Answer (score 1):

This is not Markov. Take S with 3 elements, {1,2,3}. Take A with 2, {1,2}. Say Xn = n mod 3, so stopping return times are like 1,2,(skip 3), 4, 5, (skip 6) etc. So if you're at a stopping time, you don't know which one you're at. In other words, you don't know if the next stopping time is the next time or you skip one, unless you know your position. Good luck with the rest of your 547 HW!

Comment: Well thank you! LOL I already got a counterexample of a walk on a loop! And yours also work.